# trying to center a div for mobile device/ zurb foundation

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to get this to display properly on mobile phone for the class 'circle-right right' div. Right now, instead of being centered, the circle-right class is displaying too far to the right instead of center. On desktop it displays correctly.

```
<div class="path-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row path-item">
    <div class="large-7 push-5 columns">
      <div id="img1" class="circle circle-left "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-5 pull-7 columns path-text left">
      <h3 id="pstop1">Get in touch!</h3>
      <a class="pathlinks" href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Get in touch>></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row path-item">
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <div id="img2" class="circle circle-right right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-5 columns path-text right">
      <h3 id="pstop2">Give us feedback!</h3>
      <p class="shadow">We're not happy unless your satisfied. During the process, we'll be in touch to make sure we're on the right track.</p>
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Get in touch>></a>
    </div>
```

This is most of the default css that comes with the foundation path template. Tried using media query to select the class and adjust the position, but it wont work. Here's a link to the template http://patterntap.com/code/responsive-timeline
css:

```
.path-container .path-item .circle.circle-right {

  right: 100px;
}

.path-container {
    text-align: center;
  }
   .path-container .circle {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Comment: try to remove the "padding:20px" from the class ".code-container", hope it will fix your issue!!

Comment: Remove Right and Left properties from your "circle" class. Remove - right: 0;left: 0; If you have a fiddle i can solve and show you.

Comment: @kirkan do u mean the html or css

Comment: thanks problem solved, please write an answer so i can mark as best @kirkan.